# XSL: Intersecting two sorted blocks

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, intersection

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<block1>
 <node>
  <name>A<name/>
 <node/>
 <node>
  <name>B<name/>
 <node/>
 ...
</block1>

<block2>
 <node>
  <name>B<name/>
 <node/>
 <node>
  <name>D<name/>
 <node/>
 ...
</block2>
```

The entrees of each block are sorted based on the name.

I want to create a table that will hold all of the names that belong in block1 and block2.
How can I do this efficiently (using the fact that the nodes are sorted)?

Comment: You may want to have a look at my XPath 3.0 implementation of a Binary Tree data structure, and of a Set data type, based on BST. Apart from this, a very efficient solution exists using keys -- it doesn't even use the fact that the values are sorted.

Comment: I have posted an answer using keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A solution using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kB1NodeByVal" match="block1/node" use="name"/>
 <xsl:key name="kB2NodeByVal" match="block2/node" use="name"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDistinctB1Nodes" select=
 "/*/block1/node
      [generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kB1NodeByVal',name)[1])
       ]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="$vDistinctB1Nodes[key('kB2NodeByVal', name)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the (corrected from severe malformedness) provided XML document**:

```
<t>
    <block1>
        <node>
            <name>A</name>
        </node>
        <node>
            <name>B</name>
        </node>
 ...
    </block1>
    <block2>
        <node>
            <name>B</name>
        </node>
        <node>
            <name>D</name>
        </node>
 ...
    </block2>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<node>
   <name>B</name>
</node>
```

**The efficiency of this solution is O(k), where `k` is the number of distinct values in Set 1**. This assumes that we have already constructed the keys (indexes) and the set of distinct values in Set 1.

Answer (score 0):

Jeni Tennison wrote a [solution](http://www.exslt.org/set/functions/intersection/set.intersection.template.xsl.html) for this in EXSLT:

```
<xsl:template name="set:intersection">
   <xsl:param name="nodes1" select="/.." />
   <xsl:param name="nodes2"select="/.." />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodes1[count(.|$nodes2) = count($nodes2)]" mode="set:intersection" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="set:intersection">
   <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is wrong -- Jeni's solution is for set intersection *by identity*. The question here is for set intersection *by value*